# Python Flask application + MySQL DB -> needing advice for the infra in AWS when latency is at stake

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, infrastructure

I have a Python Flask application and a MySQL DB with which the app connects to. The app provides RESTful APIs.

- There are around 10 pairs of (Flask and MySQL DB)s. Each pair has a unique url and environment variables.
- The API latency is crucial. One second delay for an API call is considered too much.
- However, the traffic is expected to be low. There are only tens or hundreds of API calls per day.
- all infra will be in AWS

Given the above scenarios, what is the best infra with minimum cost?

- **Question 1**: for DB, I tend to go for AWS Aurora Serverless as I pay mostly for CRUD with the DB only. Is this the best choice?
- **Question 2**: for app, I was thinking about using AWS Lambda. However, I experienced *cold start* issues with Lambda before in my Java project. I am not sure if Python Flask will be the same. If latency is at stake, what kind of should I opt for?

Comment: You need to do the benchmarking yourself. only you know / have the application logic, which is the main factor affecting performance. Create the database in different environments and measure the API performance you receive. Then you can make the decision on real data.